# Typing mongoose.connect

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, types

I'm trying to find a type for this:

```
export const connectToDatabase = ()/* here */ => mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

So far my code editor suggested this:

```
export const connectToDatabase = ():
    Promise<typeof mongoose> => mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

Which is silly. I don't want the type to be `Promise<typeof mongoose>` and it can't possibly be the desired solution. So what's the right type here? All I could find was `ConnectionUseDbOptions` and `ConnectionOptions` which doesn't work. So what's the correct type here?

Comment: What version of Mongoose do you use?

Comment: @Anatoly     `"mongoose": "^5.10.4",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `index.d.ts` in `@types/mongoose`:

```
type Mongoose = typeof mongoose;
...
export function connect(uris: string, options: ConnectionOptions, callback: (err: mongodb.MongoError) => void): Promise<Mongoose>;
export function connect(uris: string, callback: (err: mongodb.MongoError) => void): Promise<Mongoose>;
export function connect(uris: string, options?: ConnectionOptions): Promise<Mongoose>;
```

So definitely the return type is `Promise<Mongoose>` or `Promise<type of mongoose>`

Comment: This is better. Thank you!